# I need to fire leave event on bootstrap multi select but i can not also click even not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I will load data a multiselect list according to selected data pre multiselect. So i need to fire leave event but also click event not working

**HTML**

```
<select multiple id="ATRRegionTownListBox" class="form-control select">
</select>
```

**jS**

```
$("#ATRRegionTownListBox").on("click", "option", function () {
   alert('deneme');
});
```

Comment: you wanna after the blur on you select item it works something right ?

Comment: `click` seems to be working as expected? https://jsfiddle.net/qeb03hxo/

Comment: @BenM Nothing happen. <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.js"></script> this is my ref and only refresh is working if i use selectpicker like $('#ATRRegionTownListBox').selectpicker('refresh');

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem like ; Thanks everyone

```
 <select multiple id="ATRRegionTownListBox" class="form-control select">
```

```
 $(document).on('change', 'select#ATRRegionTownListBox', function () {
    alert('deneme');
    });
```